# On the iPhone, how do i parse a html page to get all the RSS links?

Tags: iphone, html, parsing

in html an rss link looks somewhat like this

```
<a class="rsslink" href="http:the_url">The feed title</a>
```

i would like to get all links that match this description from a html page that has a list of rss feeds. anyone know of a good way to parse, with some sample code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `libxml2` library can receive XPath queries with the [following extensions](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/10/using-libxml2-for-parsing-and-xpath.html). With these extensions you might issue the XPath query `/a[@class = "rsslink"]/@href` on your HTML document, in order to retrieve an `NSArray` with those attributes' values.